# Set body format for a node when it is updated via REST API

Tags: 8

I noticed that when I PATCH a node and update the body `value`, the body `format` and `summary` are set to `null`.

If I try to add the summary and format to the json sent to the API, I receive an error saying:

```
Unprocessable Entity: validation failed.
Body: this field cannot hold more than 1 values
```

Any ideas why I get this error and how can I preserve the body format?

This is my js object:

```
{
  title: { value: this.state.title }, 
  body: { value: this.state.body, format: "basic_html" }, 
  type: { target_id: 'article' },
  _links: {
    type: {
      href: 'http://localsite.dev/rest/type/node/article'
    }
  },
}
```

If I remove the `format: "basic_html"` part, I get no errors but the format and summary are set to null.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of surprised this even works. The value of a field is a list of field items. Try something like this:

```
body: [ { value: this.state.body, format: "basic_html" } ],
```

Comment: Why surprised? It'd be surprising if this didn't work, no?

Comment: But what _is_ surprising (well, concerning), is that error message: ` this field cannot hold more than 1 values`. That makes zero sense.

Comment: Oh, it kind of does. I think what this tried to do is create a body field with two values, so basically this: [ ['value' => 'whatever was in this.state.body'], ['value' => 'basic_html']]. And it probably happened because it first ignored the array keys and made them numeric and in a second step used the two strings as value for the main property, value.

Comment: What I find surprising is how it did that upcasting example and how it accepted the thing without format, because then treated it as the value for the first field item. I know field API itself accepts pretty much anything ($node->body = $value works too, for example). But I thought the serialization API would be more strict in requiring a list of field item objects for each field.